# How to send this SQL statement in a single query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using MySQL and I want to send a statement similar to this one in a single query :

```
UPDATE fruits SET ToBuy=’yes’ WHERE Price <100, ToBuy=’no’ WHERE Price >=100
```

I know that I can divide this in 2 separate queries and it works this way but I was wondering if it is possible to do it with a single query.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: price condition is conflicting. is it a mistake or intention to do like that?

Comment: Next time its maybe better to understand your question if you write the complete two statements and not in a semi short form.

Answer (score 6):

You need a `CASE` statement:

```
UPDATE fruits
SET ToBuy = CASE WHEN Price < 100 THEN 'yes' WHEN Price >=100 THEN 'no' END
```

Of course you could just use `CASE WHEN Price < 100 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END` as well, but I've used the above clause to match your logic.

Comment: This is what I have also understood. Was about to post the answer. This is correct way to do.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `CASE` keyword would work :

```
UPDATE fruits

SET
   ToBuy = CASE WHEN Price<100 THEN  'yes'
               ELSE 'no'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Case` will help you

```
UPDATE fruits SET ToBuy = CASE when Price < 100 Then 'yes' ELSE 'no'
```

Answer (score -8):

You can call UPDATE two times.

```
UPDATE fruits SET ToBuy=’yes’ WHERE Price < 100;
UPDATE fruits SET  ToBuy=’no’ WHERE Price >= 100;
```

Comment: Not an answer, or simply conflicting with the questions specifications.